# extract and rebuild key value pairs for json

Tags: php, json

I currently have an array with key-value pairs that looks like this for example:

```
Array(
  (int) 250 => 'blue',
  (int) 252 => 'green',
  (int) 289 => 'yellow'
)
```

That's the format I get when I debug it.

```
I need it to be formatted as follows:
['key':250,'value':'blue'],
['key':252,'value':'green'],
['key':289,'value':'yellow']
```

So basically I need it to be "key" equals "a value" & "value" = "a value"

This array will then be serialized to json.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Proper json would be something like {"250":"blue", "252": "green", "289": "yellow"}. Why the weird intermediate data format?

Comment: I don't really know how else to do it. When I try to _serialize the array as is, it fails. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: I don't know PHP really but according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php just doing `json_encode()` with the Array you have there should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**in your controller:**

```
if($this->RequestHandler->responseType() == 'json'){
    $data = array(
       (int) 250 => 'blue',
       (int) 252 => 'green',
       (int) 289 => 'yellow'
     );
    $this->set('data', $data);
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
}
```

**in your routers.php**

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

call for example: http://localhost/mycontroller/myaction.json

**result**

```
{"250":"blue","252":"green","289":"yellow"}
```

**OR**

```
$data= array(
   (int) 250 => 'blue',
   (int) 252 => 'green',
   (int) 289 => 'yellow'
 );
 foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
     $data[] = array('key'=> $key,'value'=> $value);
 } 
$this->set('data', $data);
$this->set('_serialize', 'data');
```

**result**

```
[{"key":250,"value":"blue"},{"key":252,"value":"green"},{"key":289,"value":"yellow"}]
```